# Web essentials - Run on build events

Tags: web-essentials

I am working on a project using Web Essentials to bundle and minify script files.

It works perfectly well and Web Essentials run when I save changes the to script files. We are currently several developers on the project and we face a problem every time we get changes from our source control (TFS). Changes to the script files does not trigger Web Essentials to run, unless we manually edit and save a script file. Since we have a few projects, we currently have to do this for every project.

**Is it possible to trigger Web Essentials to run on builds (build events)?**

I noticed that the bundle files include an attribute called 'runOnBuild'. This is set to true, but does not seem to do the trick.

I am also open for suggestions on alternative approaches (trigger via TypeScript compiler, etc.)

Comment: Do you have an answer on this question? I would like to use this also

Comment: Can you please share how do you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In the source code of Web Essentials I found out that [Web Essentials](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2012/tree/master/packages) uses [AjaxMin](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxMin). It is possible to create a build task for AjaxMin according to this thread: [AjaxMin Build Task to minify all js to separate folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146832/ajaxmin-build-task-to-minify-all-js-to-separate-folder)