# AjaxMin Build Task to minify all js to separate folder

Tags: ajaxmin

I m using **ajaxmin** to minify all my JS files. Everything works perfectly but i have little problem with the way the output files are generated.

Currently what happenes is the JS files are minified next to its path. e.g If the original path is **includes/js/test.js** then it is minified at **includes/js/test.min.js**.

I want my all js files to minify at different location then the original location. e.g. My all js files are under **includes/js/JSFILESHERE** and i wanted these js files to be minified at **includes/minifiedjs/MINIFIEDJSFILESHERE**.

i m using the below code.

```
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\MicrosoftAjax\AjaxMin.tasks" />
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        <ItemGroup>
            <JS Include="\js\*.js" Exclude="**\*.min.js;" />
        </ItemGroup>  
    <AjaxMin JsSourceFiles="@(JS)" JsSourceExtensionPattern="\js\.js$" JsTargetExtension=".min.js"/>
    </Target>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for replying bit late to this question.

Here is the solution I used for my project -

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<PropertyGroup>
  <DestinationPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\build-publish</DestinationPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <JS Include="Scripts\app\**\*.js" Exclude="**\*.min.js;Scripts\*.js" />
</ItemGroup>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(JS)" DestinationFiles="@(JS -> '$(DestinationPath)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename).src%(Extension)')" Condition="'%(Extension)'=='.js'">
  <Output ItemName="JavaScriptFiles" TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" />
</Copy>
<AjaxMin JsSourceFiles="@(JavaScriptFiles)" JsSourceExtensionPattern="\.src.js$" JsTargetExtension="min.js" SourceMapType="V3">
</AjaxMin>
```

Here am first copying the files to a destination folder(recursively) and then applying the Minification on them. I needed source map files so thats why I kept my original files but if you dont need source maps then you could delete source files after minification is complete.